# Is it possible to use same DNS for 2 domain name to access files ?

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

I just purchase a hosting panel from **Godaddy** and I've  2 domain name which is purchase from another 2 web domain hosting company.

a) x
b) y.

**X** is live and it's **DNS** is set from **Godaddy** hosting panel.

So now I want to use same **DNS** for **Y**. Is it possible ? So that my both sites file will be exits in **Godaddy Hosting Panel**

How can I do this ?
Can I create another sub-folder for **Y** ? Thanks for your suggestions.